# CSS v. Using a PNG for a drop shadow

Tags: html, css, dropshadow

I'm curious as to what would be the better approach for a drop shadow in terms of load on the browser: to generate the shadow w CSS or to use a PNG that is 1px tall by 18px wide that would repeat over the height of the container.

I have a background in 2D animation using Flash/Adobe animate and Action Script 2 and 3 and it was easier on the computing to use a PNG instead of the drop shadow that was built in. I'm wondering if the same would be true in HTML/CSS or if the extra http request outweighs what it takes for the CSS to do it. Thoughts?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUQVf.png

-cac

Comment: Hi Cory, this seems like something you can easily measure yourself. Have you done that? We can't really provide an answer without more detail (like a [mcve] which includes the PNG and CSS code you have in mind), making this question currently primarily opinion-based.

Comment: In Flash/ActionScript, it was a hard and fast answer that the PNG performed better than having to generate the drop shadow on the export. I was wondering if the same was true for HTML/CSS for the way the browser renders drop shadows v. calls PNGs. I could test it myself, but was thinking maybe someone here had experience with this issue. My internet searches proved unfruitful, so I came here.

Comment: The result will depend on the size of the SVG, the connection of the end user and your server providing the image, or the same but the CSS... in other words, you have to test to know. But I can say with some amount of confidence it won't matter much.

Comment: I think OP is more wanting to know on the [rendering / compositor vs raster thread processing](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/inside-browser-part3) aspects that are up to the user agent instead of passing a file size across the wire. In which case they are treated differently when painted. It can vary between browsers but generally the CSS way is GPU optimized but the effect is calc'd vs just rendered which is why the png can often win.

Comment: Yes, Chris W., thanks for that. That was my thinking, I just wasn't sure if it worked similarly as it did in Flash or if it had been optimized to the point where it really didn't matter much any more. It just seems like the calculation would make things slower than throwing up a PNG, but just wasn't sure if that was true. It might still be the case that the difference is so small it's almost negligible, even if it does lean towards PNG. @ChrisW.

Comment: @CoryCasella yea, I can say with relative confidence especially with static shadowing on contemporary browsers the difference would be pretty trivial. When you get into like adding transitions / keyframe anims, etc then it can become an issue. Or if you're giving everything that never needed a shadow a shadow anyway. Otherwise you're probably not going to notice a diff, but....only one way to find out..on each browser :D

Comment: Oh on that note, if you plan on supporting legacy internet explorer...I feel bad for you either way, it + even simple things like shadows or even rounded box corners is no bueno haha.

Comment: @ChrisW. The size of the SVG and the CSS (read: complexity) matter during rendering as well as transmission rates, which is why connection was just *part* of what was needed to know. :-)

Comment: @tylerh it’s not an svg im talking about though. I was asking  about a PNG. An SVG would need to be calculated in a similar way the css shadow would. The png would just be displayed and repeated.

Comment: @CoryCasella Sorry, slip of the tongue; I meant PNG, not SVG.